# Discord.js bot command to take users with a specific role and to return an embedded message with all the users in that role

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots, embed, roles

I've been working on this and I cannot figure out why the bot will not enact the command. Essentially this is how the situation should work:

1. In the channel you send a message: "!listroletest"
2. After that, the bot should send an embedded with every user who has the role "test" with their userID's

```js
client.on("message", message => {

    if(message.content == "!listroletest") {
        
            const ListEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Users with the test role:')
            .setDescription(message.guild.roles.get('901592912171765850').members.map(m=>m.user.tag).join('\n'));
            message.channel.send(ListEmbed);                    
        }
});
```

Comment: Have you checked that the event emits and that the if-statement fires? Also ensure you have the guild messages intent enabled

Comment: are you using the newest Discord.js version? If so, the "message" event has been replaced with "messageCreate".